# How can I call the string from a textbox from other WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

i have a little problem at getting the string from a textbox that is in a other wpf window. Can anybody help?

Comment: i make it like that: 
Examplewindow window = new Examplewindow();
window.Show();
this.Close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to another open window in the application using the `Application.Current.Windows` property:

```
var window1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window1>().FirstOrDefault();
if (window1 != null)
{
    string text = window1.textBlock1.Text;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an instance of the window you could easily access the `TextBox` using the instance.

```
var otherWindow = new MainWindow();
otherWindow.Show();

// ....

var text = otherWindow.NameOfTheTextBox.Text;
```

So you don't have to use `Application.Current.Windows`.

Comment: This is a better option than the accepted answer. +1

Comment: I know you are trying to help, but before i asked this question i already tried it but it dont worked at me

Comment: @SarperEroglu maybe you can share a bit more code, because as your comment reveals you have an instance of the window. So this approach should normally work too.

Comment: @slow im sorry but thats an important project for me and i cant share it sorry :(